# How to create a responsive circles in css using vw units?

Tags: html, css, unit-testing

I created two circles of same size using CSS. The output on desktop screen is fine as by coding. But when i view the output on phone, the circle overlaps. I heard VW units are good for responsive page design. That's why i am using VW units. Any other techniques are also welcomed.

HTML:

```
   <div class="circle1"> Hello I am a Circle1 </div>
   <div class="circle2"> Hello I am a Circle2 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle1
    {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
    color:#F7FAF7;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background:#000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0vh;
    left: 0vw;
    }    
.circle2
    {
     width:100px;
     height: 100px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     font-size: 10px;
     color:#F7FAF7;
     line-height: 100px;
     text-align: center;
     background:#000;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0vh;
     left: 8vw;
     }
```

Comment: Can you make a sketch of what you try to accomplish in both desktop and mobile?

Comment: I need several circles spaced some distance apart. Right now i am trying with only two circles.

Comment: is position fixed compulsory?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/e158fra0/

Comment: no not at all...

Comment: position them relative and make them display inline-block; remove the left property. and give a try

Comment: exactly.. Thanks.. Can i place one circle at centre of page and place all other circles around main circle?

Comment: Like so? https://jsfiddle.net/p9ytsb5d/1/ This still needs a lot of work but you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very open ended, as what you write in code depends on what exactly you want.

If you're looking for a row of circles, perhaps you should use float.
It will cause your circles to move in next line if there's not enough space in that line. Also, it'll look good on all devices as nothing overlaps or scales down.

Sample:

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #F7FAF7;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"> Hello I am a Circle1 </div>
<div class="circle"> Hello I am a Circle2 </div>
<div class="circle"> Hello I am a Circle3 </div>
<div class="circle"> Hello I am a Circle4 </div>
```

If you're looking for a center circle with all other circles aligned around it, maybe position relative is better. But this doesn't look like the kind of design which will look good on mobile devices.

Sample:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #F7FAF7;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #abf;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #F7FAF7;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #456;
}

.pos1 {
  top: 120px;
  left: 0px;
}

.pos2 {
  top: -120px;
  left: 0px;
}

.pos3 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 120px;
}

.pos4 {
  top: 0px;
  left: -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  Main circle
  <div class="circle pos1"> Hello I am a Circle1 </div>
  <div class="circle pos2"> Hello I am a Circle2 </div>
  <div class="circle pos3"> Hello I am a Circle3 </div>
  <div class="circle pos4"> Hello I am a Circle4 </div>
</div>
```